# RGB color codes in Semantic Segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, semantic-segmentation

I am using the Semantic Segmentation network (SegNet). I am trying to reduce the number of classes and thus rearranging the network.

Therefore, I am also changing the color-coding of the predictions as well. My problem is I don't get the intended colors in the output image.

For e.g.

```
pascal_palette = np.array([(0, 0, 0),
                           (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0),
                           (0, 0, 128), (0, 128, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (128, 0, 0),
                           (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)
                        ], dtype=np.uint8)
```

The above line gives perfect results for the three classes as the pixels are only in 1 channel.

The output is as below:

[image: Gives results as expected]

However, if I modify the line and add values to different channels it gives weird output. The output is attached below:

```
pascal_palette = np.array([(0, 0, 0),
                           (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0),
                           (0, 0, 128), (124, 252, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (128, 0, 0),
                           (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)
                            ], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Changed the color code to (124, 252, 0). The code should be for lawn green color. I also checked it on a website like [RBG codes](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html)

[image: All become red]

What am I missing here? Any explanation will be helpful.

Prediciton code:

```
 prob = model.predict(net_in)[0]

    # Reshape to 2d here since the networks outputs a flat array per channel
    prob_edge = np.sqrt(prob.shape[0]).astype(np.int)
    prob = prob.reshape((prob_edge, prob_edge, 13))

    # Upsample
    if args.zoom > 1:
        prob = interp_map(prob, args.zoom, image_size[1], image_size[0])

    # Recover the most likely prediction (actual segment class)
    prediction = np.argmax(prob, axis=2)

    # Apply the color palette to the segmented image
    color_image = np.array(pascal_palette)[prediction.ravel()].reshape(
        prediction.shape + (3,))

    print('Saving results to: ', args.output_path)
    with open(args.output_path, 'wb') as out_file:
        Image.fromarray(np.multiply(color_image,255)).save(out_file)
```

PS. I have used same model for predictions in both case

Comment: How are you plotting these images? How can you make a full image from so few pixels?

Comment: The predictions are not wrong, if you have good eyes and monitor, when you look closely enough, you will see the same regions as in the "correct" image, but using a just a little bit darker red. --- The whole problem lies in how you're plotting the images.

Comment: The colored pixels are of 3 objects road, car and poles. The predicted image is of a highway. Thus, most of it is covered.

Comment: @DanielMöller I am simply dumping the image using Image.fromarray(np.multiply(color_image,255)).save(out_file)

Comment: I presume I should see some yellowish green pixels instead of red for the values (124, 252,0). It should be red ( light or dark ).

Comment: That doesn't really explain what you're doing. How are you converting predictions into images? How does the pallete participate in the conversion? What are the max and min values of `color_image`? etc. Please explain it in detail so people can help you.

Comment: I suspect you may have values greater than 255 for some reason, a simple try is to make that orange pixel a little darker: `(124,180,0)`. If it works, this may prevent some bug from happening, but doesn't identify and fix the bug.

Comment: ok, i will try to make orange little darker. I have updated the question with prediction related code. thank you for providing info.

Comment: the prediction out of the model are one hot coded?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very probably in `np.multiply(color_image,255)`.

As you created a pallete already with values from 0 to 255 and you're simply gathering values from this pallete, you don't need to multiply it by 255.

Use simply `Image.fromarray(color_image).save(out_file)`.